# PHPUnit prints require to terminal instead of loading the file

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm not very familiar with PHP and struggling with the PHPUnit setup for hours. This is the situation:

- `functions.php` - contains functions to be tested

```php
<?
/**
 * test function
 */
function simple($url){
    return true
}
```

- `phpunit.xml` - PHPUnit configuration

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name='Functions tests'>
            <directory prefix="" suffix=".test.php">./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

- `tests/functions.test.php` - contains the unit tests for the functions

```php
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class FunctionsTest extends TestCase {
    public function test_simple(){
        $this->assertEquals(simple(), true);
    }
    ...
}
```

- `tests/bootstrap.php` - bootstrapping file for the unit tests
  The content of `bootstrap.php` is:

```php
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../functions.php');
```

I then run `php vendor/bin/phpunit` which has a weird output.

1. The content of the `functions.php` file gets printed to the terminal
2. All tests fail with `Call to undefined function simple`

When I copy the content of `functions.php` in front of the `functions.test.php` all tests pass, but this shouldn't be the solution.

Comment: Can you share the contents of functions.php? Or the first few lines, covering the first function?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `<?` with `<?php` in your `functions.php`

Comment: unbelievable.... this solved the problem

Comment: @Lukas I am not sure if you are just trying to get into PHP or similar, but I would recommend to use Laravel, a framework, because you have an excellent documentation about anything, also about testing, so it is going to be way easier for you to get into that, and I am not even mentioning the vast community it has with it help.